# moverse a un elemento en concreto de la pagina web

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

lo que quiero es que cuando pulse un link (el que esta abajo de todo de la pagina), la pagina que se recarga se desplace hasta dicho link. Mi codigo es este:

```js
function moverseA(idDelElemento) {
    location.hash = "#" + idDelElemento;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click",'.boton', function(event) {
        //alert("hola");
        moverseA("foto");
    }); 
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="utilidades.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <img src="https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02nLKyOIM9yGPQNWynhIptQA4lS3w:1623696769947&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=url+imagenes+de+ejemplo&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiD6cfp5ZfxAhUK1RoKHejuDO4QjJkEegQIAhAC&biw=1294&bih=656#imgrc=rdiYERqSWdV3jM"  style="width:500px;">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02nLKyOIM9yGPQNWynhIptQA4lS3w:1623696769947&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=url+imagenes+de+ejemplo&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiD6cfp5ZfxAhUK1RoKHejuDO4QjJkEegQIAhAC&biw=1294&bih=656#imgrc=rdiYERqSWdV3jM"  style="width:500px;">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02nLKyOIM9yGPQNWynhIptQA4lS3w:1623696769947&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=url+imagenes+de+ejemplo&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiD6cfp5ZfxAhUK1RoKHejuDO4QjJkEegQIAhAC&biw=1294&bih=656#imgrc=rdiYERqSWdV3jM"  style="width:500px;">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02nLKyOIM9yGPQNWynhIptQA4lS3w:1623696769947&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=url+imagenes+de+ejemplo&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiD6cfp5ZfxAhUK1RoKHejuDO4QjJkEegQIAhAC&biw=1294&bih=656#imgrc=rdiYERqSWdV3jM"  style="width:500px;">
        <img id="foto" src="https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02nLKyOIM9yGPQNWynhIptQA4lS3w:1623696769947&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=url+imagenes+de+ejemplo&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiD6cfp5ZfxAhUK1RoKHejuDO4QjJkEegQIAhAC&biw=1294&bih=656#imgrc=rdiYERqSWdV3jM"  style="width:1000px;">
        <a id='boton' class='boton' href='index.php'>Pulsar</a>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

No consigo que se mueva al link cuando pulso dicho link.

Comment: Chequea que es la ruta correcta , acabo de chequear tu html y no tuve problemas.

Comment: No hay ningún elemento con el _anchor_ "foto", ¿a dónde esperas que se mueva?

Comment: cierto, me faltaba el anchor "foto" ya esta correjido y funciona en el snippet perfectamente, pero te juro que en mi ordenador no funciona.

Comment: Tu caso es el mismo de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/462122/54039), solo necesitas cancelar el evento: `event.preventDefault();` para evitar que el enlace te lleve a otra página.

Comment: perfecto! eso funciono, gracias!