# Limpiar inputs de un formulario php

Tags: php, jquery

estoy tratando de limpiar un formulario con inputs de fecha.
Estaba usando el input `type reset`, pero si algún valor ya existía, se regresa a el.
Ahora trato de usar jquery, pero no se que error estoy cometiendo.

[image: gif explicativo del error]

Solo busco que el `btn-reset` me limpie los inputs de fechas.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $fechaI = $fechaF = "";
    echo "FI - " . $_POST['fechaI'] . "</br>";
    echo "FF - " . $_POST['fechaF'] . "</br>";
    if (isset($_POST['fechaI']) && !empty($_POST['fechaI'])) {
        $fechaI = $_POST['fechaI'];
        echo $fechaI . "</br>";
        if (isset($_POST['fechaF']) && !empty($_POST['fechaF'])) {
            $fechaF = $_POST['fechaF'];
            echo $fechaF . "</br>";
        } else {
            $fechaF_error = "Error con Fecha Final </br>";
            echo $fechaF_error;
        }
    } else {
        $fechaI_error = "Error con Fecha Inicial </br>";
        echo $fechaI_error;
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rev. Con2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        Fechas -
        Desde: <input type="date" name="fechaI" id="fechaI" style="width:15vw; margin: 5px; height: 3vh;" value="<?php if (isset($_POST["fechaI"])) {
                                                                                                                        echo $_POST["fechaI"];
                                                                                                                    } ?>">

        Hasta: <input type="date" name="fechaF" id="fechaF" style="width:15vw; margin: 5px; height: 3vh;" value="<?php if (isset($_POST["fechaF"])) {
                                                                                                                        echo $_POST["fechaF"];
                                                                                                                    } ?>">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Buscar</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="reset" id="btn-reset">Limpiar</button>
    </form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btn-reset").on("click", function() {
        // Cancelar comportamiento normal del botón
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#fechaI').val('');
        $('#fechaF').val('');
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: `$('#fechaI').val('');` no es `javascript`, es `Jquery`...

Comment: corrigo de inmediato, en cuanto al resto del codigo, como deberia ser entonces ?

Comment: Creo que solo falta `event.preventDefault();` para evitar el comportamiento normal del botón, que es devolver los valores a como estaban inicialmente.

Comment: Si me lo puedes dejar en respuesta Triby, siempre tengo confusiones entre js y jquery :C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que solo falta cancelar el evento, para evitar que el botón `reset` vuelva a poner todo como estaba originalmente:

```js
$("#btn-reset").on("click", function(e) {
    // Cancelar comportamiento normal del botón
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#fechaI').val('');
    $('#fechaF').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        Fechas -
        Desde: <input type="date" name="fechaI" id="fechaI" style="width:15vw; margin: 5px; height: 3vh;" 
        value="2021-05-15">
                
        Hasta: <input type="date" name="fechaF" id="fechaF" style="width:15vw; margin: 5px; height: 3vh;" 
        value="2021-06-15">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Buscar</button>
        <button id="btn-reset">reset</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: @Excorpion, en el fragmento de código funciona correctamente.

Comment: Encontrado mi error, debía agregar el link de jquery, gracias Triby !!